# How to hide a form from a panel in another class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I want to hide a form in panel1(form content) using this code:

```
frmChangePassword frmChangePassword = new frmChangePassword();
frmChangePassword.Hide();
```

with no luck. Here is my code to display in a panel:

```
//SHOW CHANGEPASSWORD FORM
if (isChangePasswordActive == false)
{
     isChangePasswordActive = true;
     frmChangePassword frmChangePassword = new frmChangePassword();
     frmChangePassword.TopLevel = false;
     frmChangePassword.Parent = this.panel1;
     frmChangePassword.Show();   
}
```

Is there a way to clear the content in my panel and display a new form in the same panel?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Favor raising an event instead of making a class aware of the implementation details of your UI.  Say a NeedPassword event.  Your form can subscribe the event and make the panel content visible.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of the Password form. You need to get the current instance and then hide it. There are two ways I can think of:

1. Retain the frmChangePassword object you have created to show the form and call hide method on that object. You may have to change the scope of that object.
2. Use Application.OpenForms collection to get the opened instance of password form and hide it.

I would go with first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you're creating a *new* form and then hiding the panel on that form. You can tell because you used the `new` keyword:

```cs
frmChangePassword frmChangePassword = new frmChangePassword();
frmChangePassword.Hide();  // affects the ^^ NEW instance ^^ you just created!!
```

So the code actually works fine in that it does exactly what it's supposed to be doing, it just doesn't produce the result you intended, which was to hide the panel on the *existing instance* of the form.

That gets a little bit tricker, because you have to find a way to get a reference to the existing instance of the form. In order to tell you how to redesign your code to do that, I'd have to see more of the code. Generally, the method you're writing this code in (the one that needs to do the hiding) will take a parameter of type `Form` (or even `frmChangePassword`), and the caller will pass in the current instance of the form to be modified.

Comment: You are correct, i have a form which is frmMain that contains splitpanel. On the splitcontainer.panel2 i want to show form1 and when i click a button in frmMain.splitcontainer.panel1, form1 must hide and form2 should show. What happen is that form1 and form2 is shown form1 is at the top something like form1.BringToFront(). what i want is to close form1.. here's the code //HIDE FORM CHANGEPASSWORD
            frmChangePassword frmChangePassword = new frmChangePassword();
            frmChangePassword.Hide();

Answer (score 0):

If you still need it.
You have to declare a global varible of type Form in your public class:

```
    Form frm = new Form();
```

Every time you trigger a new form load be sure to put first: frm.Hide();
and then intitialize the variable with the new form that will show:

```
        frm.Hide();
        frm = new thenewForm() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false, TopMost = true };
        this.yourPanel.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Show();
```

The properties I put in the "{" might change depending on the style you want, but if you want to have it as a borderless window you can copy those.